# Pressing Enter the button doesn't submit, only clicking the button

Tags: html, css, button, onclick, click

So this is a button inside my Login modal and only submit when I click on the button, but I want that the client can press Enter and submit as well, but doesn't work!

**Here's my < button >:**

```
<button id="loginsubmitbutton" type="submit" 
class="btn btn-default">Enter</button>
```

**Here's my < script >:**

```
<script>
    console.log('script')

    $('#loginsubmitbutton').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('estou aqui')


        let username = $("#username").val();
        let password = $("#password").val();

      let data = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/',
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (data) {
          window.location.href = '/dashboard';
            },
          error: function () {
           $('#alert').append(
             `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="font-size: 11px; color: #c50e0e;">
                    Invalid username or password. Please, try again.</div>`)
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're using a click function. You might use a form submit event instead, or add a keyup event for code 13.

Comment: thank you! used the <form> around my inputs and it worked! :))